# tikzpicture curve partly displayed

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, curve-fitting

I would like to plot in the same graph a theoretical plot and some experimental measurements. The pgfplot displays only a part of it (see image).

[image]

Here is what I compile:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
     xlabel={angle $\alpha$ (\degree)},
    ylabel={power (mW)},
        ymajorgrids=true,
        xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot [color=red]{ 100 * ( cos( x -14) )^2};
%\addlegendentry{model}
\addplot [mark=.,only marks, error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both,x fixed=1,
    y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
(14,    98.5)
(15,    98.1) 
(20,    93.9) 
(25,    84.8) 
(30,    71.69) 
(35,    55.1)
(40,    38.8) 
(45,    20.4) 
(50,    10.2) 
(55,    1.7) 
(59,    0) 
(60,    0.1) 
};
%\addlegendentry{experimental data}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. That is because the default domain for function plotting is from -5 to 5. Just add `domain=0:60`(or whatever) to either the `axis` or the `\addplot` options.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Why is it not by default plotted in the all area ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please make your code snippet compilable ...

Comment: This would be a race condition. You haven't stated some axis limits, which are automatically "calculated" from the `\addplot` commands. So when you only would plot the function (and haven't explicitly set some axis limits), there are no axis limits and so the function cannot know from where to where to plot.

Comment: If my answer below was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409467/tikzpicture-curve-partly-displayed#comment1021976_409467) you need to add `domain=<xmin>:<xmax>` to either the `axis` or the `\addplot` options to achieve the desired result.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % (better practice is to write the degree symbol directly at the ticklabels)
        xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
        xlabel={angle $\alpha$},
        ylabel={power (mW)},
        ymajorgrids=true,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
    ]
        \addplot [
            color=red,
            domain=0:60,        % <-- added
        ] {100*cos(x-14)^2};

        \addplot [
            mark=.,
            only marks,
            error bars/.cd,
                x dir=both,x fixed=1,
%                % (there are not given any error values)
%                y dir=both,y explicit,
        ] coordinates {
            (14, 98.5)
            (15, 98.1)
            (20, 93.9)
            (25, 84.8)
            (30, 71.69)
            (35, 55.1)
            (40, 38.8)
            (45, 20.4)
            (50, 10.2)
            (55, 1.7)
            (59, 0)
            (60, 0.1)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]